# What is an empty account if the state root is not empty?

Tags: security, accounts, attacks, state-trie

["State-bloat"](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/10/13/announcement-imminent-hard-fork-eip150-gas-cost-changes) attacks led to an [empty account being defined](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5es5g4/a_state_clearing_faq) as an account that has zero balance, nonce and code.

There was a [disagreement on EIP 161](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/161#issuecomment-256460614):

> I disagree. An account should be considered empty when the code,
>   nonce, balance and state root is empty.

Is it possible to have an empty account with a non-empty state root?  What is the difference between requiring the state root to be empty or not?