# How did the "state clearing" transactions run Out of Gas?

Tags: accounts, out-of-gas, consensus, exceptions, blockchain-fork

"*Failing to revert empty account deletions when the **transaction causing the deletions of [empty accounts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10134/why-were-empty-accounts-allowed-to-be-on-the-blockchain) ended with an out-of-gas exception***" [caused issues](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/25/security-alert-11242016-consensus-bug-geth-v1-4-19-v1-5-2) with consensus on November 24 2016.

Usually, a transaction provides a comfortable cushion of gas so that it doesn't reach an out-of-gas exception.  For example, if one thinks their transaction might consume 500K gas, specifying 1M gas for it seems reasonable since all unused gas will be refunded.

Testing a transaction for Out of Gas (OOG) must also have been performed (because transactions either complete or OOG), so what are the details?

1. **How** did the "state clearing" transactions run OOG?
2. Were there several primary ways that they ran OOG?  If so, how can they be **classified** so that the community keeps them in mind for their own testing?