# During which blocks did the DDos attack create millions of empty accounts?

Tags: accounts, attacks, dos

This post ([Why were empty accounts allowed to be on the blockchain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10134/why-were-empty-accounts-allowed-to-be-on-the-blockchain)) discusses the Ddos attack from fall 2016. It mentions that nearly 20,000,000 account were created and then immediately deleted causing a huge bloat in the state trie. Does anyone know during which blocks those Ddos attacks were created?

If one were to ever try to create an index of accounts, that index would become unnecassarily bogged down. If one knew during which blocks they were created, one could simply skip these accounts given that they would be deleted soon thereafter by the hard fork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Why is my node synchronization stuck/extremely slow at block 2,306,843?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9883/why-is-my-node-synchronization-stuck-extremely-slow-at-block-2-306-843):

> 2,421,507 to 2,463,130 - Account bloat transactions where 19 million empty accounts were created. This causes the node clients to slow down as the many accounts cannot be kept in cache requiring slow re-retrieval from disk.

From [Ethereum Network Attacker’s IP Address Is Traceable](https://www.bokconsulting.com.au/blog/ethereum-network-attackers-ip-address-is-traceable/), there were two contracts deployed to execute this attack:

- [0x6a0a0fc761c612c340a0e98d33b37a75e5268472](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6a0a0fc761c612c340a0e98d33b37a75e5268472) created in block [#2,421,490](https://etherscan.io/block/2421490) with the first transaction in block [#2,421,507](https://etherscan.io/block/2421507) and the last transaction in block [#2,435,148](https://etherscan.io/block/2435148).
- [0x7c20218efc2e07c8fe2532ff860d4a5d8287cb31](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7c20218efc2e07c8fe2532ff860d4a5d8287cb31) created in block [#2,423,558](https://etherscan.io/block/2423558) with the first transaction in block [#2,423,577](https://etherscan.io/block/2423577) and the last transaction in block [#2,463,130](https://etherscan.io/block/2463130).